# How to handle downloaded Images with CATiledLayer

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, catiledlayer

Happy New Year,

I am writing an app where the user searches for high res images online and then downloads these large images. I need to show these in a UIScrollView.

On the Apple dev site I found the WWDC 2010 Session 104 on UIScrollViews that explains how I can use CATiledLayer with a manually created set of tiles at the various zoom levels.

Is there a way to generate the tiles programmatically from the downloaded high res image file?

Any recommendations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Starting with a CGImage (UIImage has a readonly CGImage property if you're starting with a UIImage) you can use [CGImageCreateWithImageInRect](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000956-CH1g-BAJHJABE) to create tiles from the original.

To create tiles at different zoom levels you'll probably need to draw your scaled CGImage to a graphics context and use UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext to get a UIImage containing the drawn image which you can then write out to some cache. See ["Creating and Drawing Images"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Images/Images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH13-SW1) in the Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

There's an example in a book covering Core Animation ( [link](http://pragprog.com/titles/bdcora/core-animation-for-mac-os-x-and-the-iphone) ) covering just that. Besides, the book is worth the money for the other stuff as well :-)